# Network backup sometimes failes. Ms Sql 2012 std Service Pack 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Sometimes backup fails when performing network backup with the error:

> Executing the query "BACKUP DATABASE [xxxx] TO  [xxxx Backup] W..."
>   failed with the following error: "Cannot open backup device 'xxxx
>   Backup(\\ab.cd.ef.gh\Backups1\Database_Backups\yyyy\xxxx.bak)'.
>   Operating system error 5(Access is denied.). BACKUP DATABASE is
>   terminating abnormally.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the
>   query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set
>   correctly, or connection not established correctly.

the problem that it is usually happens but sometimes successes.
I have another server with ms sql 2008 standard and this does not happen on the same network share.

Is it a problem with ms sql 2012 standard service pack 1? (I did not install any additional updates besides the service pack 1)

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like the SQL server is working fine but it is losing connectivity to the network share at some point during the backup, or the network share is slow responding (possibly due to other activity coinciding either over the network or to the same drive).

I would start by looking outside of SQL 2012 at this time to remove areas where the problem may exist before starting to dive into SQL 2012 to look for the problem.

For instance are there any differences in the network layer and then work backwards, i.e. Is it in the same subnet as the SQL 2008 server or is the SQL 2012 instance having to traverse different subnets and gateways to get to the same network share?
Is the network card hardware and software configuration identicial or similar to the SQL 2008 instance?

Is there alot of network traffic at the same time as the backup? i.e. is the network able to cope with the load being pumped through it. An easy way to test this is to change the time of the SQL 2012 backup (if possible) to try to increase the regularity of successes.

Once these bits have been cleared of causing the error then I would start looking at SQL Server - update this thread if the points so far haven't helped and I'll talk abit more on how I would approach this problem.

Might be worth checking to see if any bugs have been reported about Microsoft SQL 2012 SP1.
Let me know how you get on please :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot back up databases to a network drive if your account have not sufficient permissions to access the network drive. Please visit this link (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207187)

I hope it helps you.